# Does AppEnforce.log really log the context used for installation incorrectly?

Tags: logging, sccm, sccm-2012-r2

I have a deployment type with the following attributes:

```
Technology: MSI
Installation behavior: Install for system
Logon requirement: Whether or not a user is logged on
Installation program visibility: Hidden
```

When `msiexec` is run by the the client, the following entry is shown in AppEnforce.log:

> Executing Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe" /i "AppleApplicationSupport.msi" /qn with **user context**

This is strange since I've selected "Install for system".

Googling [reveals some speculation](https://www.reddit.com/r/SCCM/comments/27htou/packaging_pita/) that the logging is incorrect:

> for what it's worth, ive noticed that the appenforce.log seems to always say its in the user context, even when it isnt.

I found some other similar comments, but did not find any definitive reference.  This leaves me with the following questions:

Does AppEnforce.log really log the context as user even when it is executed as the system?

Comment: LocalSystem is still a user account, is it not?  At least for the context of authenticating to the security system.

Comment: @Colyn1337 I suppose it is for that particular circumstance.  The nomenclature used in SCCM is that "system context" refers to execution by the computer's account, while "user context" refers to execution by some other user (i.e. non-computer) account in AD.

Comment: Ahhhh...... Ok I follow.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: AppEnforce.log indeed logs the context incorrectly (at least for "Script Installer" technology).

### The Test

I created a deployment type with the following attributes:

```
Technology: Script Installer
Installation behavior: Install for system
Logon requirement: Whether or not a user is logged on
Installation program visibility: Hidden
Installation program: powershell .\Install-Application.ps1
```

`Install-Application.ps1` creates a log file called `script-install-test-YYYY-MM-DD__HH-MM-SS.log`.  That script is at the end of this post.

I then deployed that deployment type and watched `AppEnforce.log` and `script-install-test-X.log`.

### Results

I found the following entry in `AppEnforce.log`:

> Executing Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" .\Install-Application.ps1 with user context

Within seconds after that, the `script-install-test-X.log` was written to folder `script-install-test-SYSTEM`.  The `SYSTEM` suffix indicates that the script was run as SYSTEM.

### Conclusion

For "script installer" technology, the context written to `AppEnforce.log` messages of the style

> Executing Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" .\Install-Application.ps1 with user context

may incorrectly be written as "user context" even when the command line is executed as system context.

### What about MSI Installer Technology?

I did not perform the test for MSI Installer Technology.  However, given that the context is sometimes wrong for Script Installer Technology, the context written to `AppEnforce.log` should probably be regarded as unreliable for all deployment types regardless of technology.

### Install-Application.ps1

```
function Write-EnvToLog
{
    $appName = 'script-install-test'

    $logFolderPath = "c:\$appName-$([System.Environment]::UserName)"

    if ( -not (Test-Path $logFolderPath -PathType Container) )
    {
        New-Item -Path $logFolderPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }

    if ( -not (Test-Path $logFolderPath -PathType Container ) )
    {
        return
    }

    $logFileName = "$appName`__$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd__HH-mm-ss")).txt"

    $fp = "$logFolderPath\$logFileName"

    Get-ChildItem Env: | Out-File $fp | Out-Null

    return $true
}

try
{
    if ( Write-EnvToLog ) { "Complete!" }
    [System.Environment]::Exit(0)
}
catch
{
    [System.Environment]::Exit(1000)
}
```